# i use Laravel freamwork I don't want all of the element's information to appear in the URL

Tags: laravel

How can I send data to a controller, a section that should appear in URL `($ course-> slug_name, $ courseVideo-> slug_title,)` and a section that should not appear `($ course-> id, $ courseVideo-> id)` in URL

## Blade

```
 href="{{route('playNextVideo',[$course->slug_name,$courseVideo->slug_title, $course->id, $courseVideo->id])}}">
```

---

## Route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{course_name}'], function() {
    Route::get('{video_title}/{course_id}/{video_id}', ['as' => 'playNextVideo', 'uses' => 'Frontend\FrontendViewController@playNextVideo']);
});
```

---

## Controller

```
public function playNextVideo($courseName, $videoTitle, $courseId, $videoId) {
```

Comment: If you have 4 URL parameters, they all need to appear in the URL. If you define your route without the IDs, then you can hide them, but this brings up the question of your slugs being unique enough to substitute the requirement for the ID or not...

Comment: i usedLaravel  Accessor to get the slugs  like this function   public function getSlugNameAttribute() {
        return Str::slug($this->name);
    }

Comment: That's not what I was saying... Are the slugs unique enough that you can find a Specific course/video without having to rely on ID? If the answer to that is no, then you need the ID in the URL. If the answer is yes, then you can remove the `{course_id}` and `{video_id}` from the URL and use the slugs to find the specific video.

Comment: I understood what you mean if I don't send the id. I have to get the information using the slugs. I will try this way Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in this case, you can use just video_id and with a relationship, you can get other information like course name and section you should create course_id column in your videos database and section_id